# Embed DOC,PPT,XLS,PDF files on localhost/intranet

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to embed the following documents on a local/intra-net server

> - PDF ( Adobe Acrobat )
> - DOC/DOCX ( Microsoft Word )
> - PPT/PPTX ( Microsoft PowerPoint )
> - XLS/XLSX ( Microsoft Excel )

I had done a quiet searching online to find any php or js library to achieve this offline but all of them are online. 
Kindly let me know if you know any type of libary which assist my need.

**NOTE**
Kindly don't confuse with embedding documents on line. i know that we can embed documents on line using

```
https://docs.google.com/viewer?url={document_url}&embedded=true
```

and

```
https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src={document_url}
```

Comment: hey, have you found a solution for this question?

Comment: Sorry i didn't find any solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Azmat. After a lot of searching in nuget, npm, etc., I also concluded that there are no free/open source libraries to embed MS Office files into browser/html. Lots of paid options some with free versions but with strict limitations.

Answer (score 0):

These online URLs work by converting those types of documents to HTML format. If you want to display those documents in browsers, you'll have to convert it to HTML format as well.  If you want to do it offline without reliance on a third-party site or service, you'll need to convert them on your own server. So you'll have to find a way to convert pdf, doc, ppt and xls to HTML and host the converted HTML on your server. There is a number of tools to achieve this. I happen to know of a tool that can convert all those document types to HTML format. it is named Print2Flash. you may wish to check it or you may find another tool.

Comment: not even close @Bezz i say embed kindly concentrate on that word

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue trying to embed a pdf,ppt, doc...
After a big search in google and Stack, 
Im using ViewerJs and my website developed with Django Framework, but i needed to make a work-around, if you want to embed a pptx/ppt/pps you would need to convert to odp file.

[ViewerJS Home](http://viewerjs.org/)

I think my answer is too late, but this is so long the best solution to intranet sites and docs viewer

Comment: Hey David, can you please provide some details/code snippets/links for how you made it work?
My files are coming from database; I can go with binary/base64 to feed it to ViewerJS - the  missing piece would be how to change the MSOffice file to ODF

Comment: I don't have access to that code but this is the way to declare in HTML

<iframe src = "/Path/somefile.odp" width='400' height='300' allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe>

You need to add viewerJS to your project

Please check: 

https://viewerjs.org/instructions/

and vote if my answer was useful for you :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Basically, I'm looking for a converter. I have to have a way to convert the blob ms-office file to pdf/odf before I think about viewerjs/similar. It seems from my research, so far, there are lots of paid apps/libraries to handle Office files but no free ones. Some paid ones have free version but has some limitations on them.